# Django admin custom user model delete permission

Tags: python, django, django-admin

In my application, based on Django 1.9, I have a custom implementation of the `user` admin model and I would like to allow more than `Staff` users to delete users. I need to handle this permission programmatically.

So I've overridden `has_delete_permission` to allow to anyone to delete a user:

```
def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
    return True
```

But the admin always says this:

```
Deleting the user 'usertest@gmail.com' would result in deleting related objects, but your account doesn't have permission to delete the following types of objects:
   - user
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: What do you mean by `Stuff user`? Do you have two user models?

Comment: No only one user model, with stuff user i mean those with is_staff flag to True

Comment: How are you extending the user model? Is it through OneToOne relationship field? In that case either you need to change the `on_delete` property to `models.DO_NOTHING` or override the base user model to update the delete permission in the same way as you have done to customized user model.

Comment: I'm extending UserAdmin "class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin)"